# Manual reboot & login when Installing packages through choco via powershell script

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, choco

I've a powershell script which installs some softwares using choco.

Softwares like vagrant require reboot of the system and machine reboots on its own.

How can I make this process fully automated as in if restart is required then, it restarts and autologin and start running the script where it left off, all on its own?

If any more information is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Boxstarter](https://boxstarter.org/). It is kind of an extension to chocolatey and handles reboots automatically.

Comment: How can I implement boxstarter inside my ps script?